# How do I draw ghost notes in ABC notation?

Tags: notation, drums, abc-notation

Fairly straightforward question. I can't seem to find it in the standard or the docs. Perhaps it's just a matter of terminology.

Basically, what I'm looking for is this:

[image: Ghost Notes]

Or, more precisely, the ghost notes as written down for drums - a note head in parentheses.

Source:
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_note),
[Image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Ghost_note_drumming.png/400px-Ghost_note_drumming.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to section [4.19 Annotations](http://abcnotation.com/wiki/abc:standard:v2.1#annotations) of the ABC Standard, you can place parentheses around a note with the following code:

`"<(" ">)" C`

For example,

```
X:0
M:none
K:none
"<("">)"C2
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! I have used this at some point but could not find the example. I'm actually preparing some demos for the common drumset notation, using abcjs.